# How do I add an item to a linked list in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

Using a Comparator and Iterator, I am trying to add objects into a linked list in order. So far, I have the following:

```
public class ComparatorClass implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        return int1.compareTo(int2);
    }
}
```

and:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class OrderedListInheritance implements LinkedList {

    ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Comparator comp = new ComparatorClass();

    OrderedListInheritance(Comparator c) {
        this.comp = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object o) {
        addLast(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void addAtIndex(int index, Object o) {
        Iterator it = getIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Object element = it.next();
            if (comp.compare(element, o) < 0) {

        }else if (comp.compare(element, o) == 0) {

        }else{
            myList.add(o);
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addFirst(Object o) {
        addAtIndex(0, o);
    }

    @Override
    public void addLast(Object o) {
        addAtIndex(myList.size(), o);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
        return myList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator getIterator() {
        Iterator iter = myList.iterator();
        return iter;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return myList.indexOf(o);
    }

}
```

I am unsure how to use the Iterator in conjunction with the comparator to add each element to the Linked List in order. Can somebody help me with the logic?

Comment: There is something very strange about this question.  1) LinkedList is a class not an interface.  2)  Why would you implement a "linked list" using an ArrayList?  It won't have the computational properties of a real linked list!!!

Comment: Stephen C, what would you suggest I implement it with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparator is wrong.

Part of the general contract for a comparator is that if `compare(a, b)` is positive, `compare(b, a)` is negative.

If you pass in a comparator that does not fulfil the comparator contract, you're going to get undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you please elaborate a little more? I'd appreciate it...

Comment: From the documentation for the comparator interface: "The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all x and y." Your 'comparator' does not fulfill that contract.

Comment: @behrk2 - your compare method should read: public int compare(Integer int1, Integer int2) { return int1.compareTo(int2); } This will make it compliant with the contract of the Comparator and Comparable

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. Thanks! I updated my example above (both classes). If you look in the OrderedListInheritance class, how can I use Iterator to add an item to the LinkedList in an ordered fashion?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the `add` method to insert the element in sorted order (or anywhere but the end of the list), you are violating the contract of the `List` interface. Semantically, it's not a `List`, and it isn't safe to pass it to any code that is expecting one. Pretending to implement the `List` interface will only lead to trouble.

How about using a [`TreeSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)? instead?

```
Set<Integer> list = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

Of course, a `Set` will not permit duplicate elements.

If you want something that allows duplicates, but still allows efficient, in-order retrieval, try a heap-based collection, like [`PriorityQueue`.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you can't just use a normal `ArrayList` and then call [`Collections.sort(list)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) or [`Collections.sort(list, comparator)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)?

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
public class IntegerComparator 
    implements Comparator<Integer> 
{
    public int compare(final Integer a, final Integer b) 
    {
        return (a.compareTo(b));
    }
}
```

I was going to comment more on the code... but what you have given won't work... you declare an ArrayList but then want to use a Comparator and you are not casting... so that won't compile.

The other issue is that you should not use == 1 you should use < 0 and > 0 since the comparator may not return 1, 0, -1 but other numbers as well.  Also you are not handling all cases a < b, a == b, and a > b.

Answer (score 0):

Are we doing your homework?  Your problem seems to be not so much with the comparator interface as a clear understanding of what you want it to do.  This sounds to me like a perfect place to advocate a test driven development style.  Start by writing tests to insert into an empty list, insert to the head of a list, insert to the tail, insert in the middle of a list of length 2.  Then write tests to return the n'th element and the element with a given value.  After you have these simple cases working it will be easy to find the element in an ordered list that is the first one larger than the element to be inserted and add the element in front of the larger one.  Don't forget the edge cases of adding a duplicate value, a value smaller than any in the list and a value larger than any in the list.